# 403 forbidden error when posting in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

He all, I'm trying to post a new form, and i keep getting the following 403 error

```
Error: Forbidden
at Object.exports.error (/Users/mark/Dropbox/Programming/mine/node/botappv2/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:63:13)
at createToken (/Users/mark/Dropbox/Programming/mine/node/botappv2/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:82:55)
at Object.handle (/Users/mark/Dropbox/Programming/mine/node/botappv2/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:48:24)
at next (/Users/mark/Dropbox/Programming/mine/node/botappv2/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
at Object.handle (/Users/mark/Dropbox/Programming/mine/node/botappv2/node_modules/view-helpers/index.js:65:5)
at next (/Users/mark/Dropbox/Programming/mine/node/botappv2/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
at Object.handle (/Users/mark/Dropbox/Programming/mine/node/botappv2/config/express.js:70:7)
at next (/Users/mark/Dropbox/Programming/mine/node/botappv2/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
at Object.handle (/Users/mark/Dropbox/Programming/mine/node/botappv2/node_modules/connect-flash/lib/flash.js:21:5)
at Context.next (/Users/mark/Dropbox/Programming/mine/node/botappv2/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
```

### routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {

  app.get('/', home.index)
  app.get('/dns_servers', dns_server.index)

  app.get('/dns_servers/new', dns_server.new)
  app.post('/dns_servers/create', dns_server.create)

  app.get('/dns_servers/:id', dns_server.show)

  app.get('/dns_servers/:id/edit', dns_server.edit)
  app.post('/dns_servers/:id', dns_server.update)

  app.post('/dns_servers/:id/delete', dns_server.delete)
}
```

### form Action

```
form(action='/dns_servers/create',method='post')
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is creating a 403?

Comment: Can you post the code in `dns_server.create`?  Most likely, that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was the csrfl not being set.. I needed to set

```
        input(type="hidden", name="_csrf", value="#{csrf_token}")
```

Comment: Dude, coming back to answer your own question? Kudos.